# Fernflower decompile error

Tags: java, decompiling

I am using fernflower to decompile some projects to do some changes. I use command line to do the process. The comand I use is;

```
java -jar fernflower.jar .../binary .../source
```

What can I do to decompile all binaries successfully.

Note: JD Core or JD Gui is not an option for me.

**EDIT:** Also, for some projects, fernflower prints

```
Processing method equals (Ljava/lang/Objects;)Z ...
```

to the console and process does not move forward.

Comment: What is your problem with the current command options?

Comment: It does  not decompile the classes with inner class